# android nine-patch stretch continue pixels but not join

Tags: android, nine-patch

I had a nine-patch image below, I made some indication to stretch, but it get isn't what I want. 

[image]

the runtime effect is that:

[image]

effect is too blur, Does I miss something?

**Update 2013-08-22 original nine-patch image**
[image]

Comment: It's a normal behavior, nine patches are not designed for that kind of images.

Comment: can you please post .9.png image?

Comment: @Ȃŵåiṩ ĸîŋg I posted .9.png image, please make me correct, thanks in advance.

Comment: I suggest you to make two separate images, one with the dash line background (non-9-pathc) and another with the oval shape (9-patch) and show them with two overlapping `ImageView`s

Comment: @TactMayers Thanks your advice, as you think, with the dash line background (non-9-path) image, what's it dimension, dependence the screen width and height?

Comment: @vince i'm working on it

Comment: @Ȃŵåiṩĸîŋg just use my posted nine-patch image? Could you post your runtime screenshot?

Comment: @vince There is no horizontal gradient, it should be able to stretch horizontally, but not vertically.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

I have split the image into three parts

1. Bottom
2. Middle
3. Background

Here are the resources:

1. [image: dash_bottom.9.png]
2. [image: middle.9.png]
3. [image: back.9.png]

and here's the layout:

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/tabView" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:scaleType="fitXY" android:src="@drawable/back" />
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView1" android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView1" android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView1" android:scaleType="fitXY" android:src="@drawable/middle" />
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView3" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView1" android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView1" android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1" android:scaleType="fitXY" android:src="@drawable/dash_bottom" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: thank you guy, If you facing that problem or someone like that, do you have other way to solve? please give me some suggestion.

Comment: I think second way is to use some image editing softwares like Photoshop, Gimp to edit the picture and stretch it.

Comment: make a whole width image?

Comment: yes, or just remove bottom line from that image then use 9-patch

Comment: whole width image is too absolutely, nine-patch obviously is prefect choice. according in you suggest, we should be has three images, first: background image without dash line(9-patch); second: dash line image(9-patch); third: oval shape(9-patch). after that, should I join the three images into a selector?

Comment: thanks your tried, but use relativelayout is too complex for me, I'll try the three images solution, and then I'll post my way.

Comment: please check my new answer.

Answer (score 0):

As I said, I ask my workmate to split original image as three images:

1 : background image without dash line(9-patch)
[image]

2 : dash line image(9-patch)
[image]

3 : oval shape(9-patch)
[image]

I used a layer-list to make it together, below is runtime screen shot(still had some design problem):
[image]

my layout define is :

```
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
                  android:background="@drawable/title_bg_content_area">

        <Button android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" android:background="@drawable/title_item_selected"
                android:text="文字" android:textSize="20sp" android:textColor="#fefffc" />

        <Button android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" android:background="@null"
                android:text="有声" android:textSize="20sp" android:textColor="#b1d596" />

        <Button android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" android:background="@null"
                android:text="本地" android:textSize="20sp" android:textColor="#b1d596" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<layer-list>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/title_bg" />
    <item android:top="50dp">
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/title_bg_wrap_line" android:tileMode="repeat" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: that is not perfect, I'll try Canvas&BitmapDrawable&NinePatchDrawable.

Comment: @Ȃŵåiṩĸîŋg sorry, I cannot check your image, request is Forbidden.

Comment: oh, see here: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B5kqDjrsjno9QmNnYlYtVjRaWjg/edit?usp=drive_web